# *Change activity background on application load (before onCreate)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, background, oncreate

I have the following problem:

When I start my activity, its default background is set to white. I can change it in onCreate method. If I use this method to change the background, I have something like 2 seconds of white background every time I start the activity.

**Is there any way to have background that I chose (for example black) from the beginning of application life?**

Comment: Why don't you set the background in the layout file itself?

Comment: I don't know how to set the background of Activity itself. I know how to set children background, for example Layout background...

Comment: Just set the background to your root layout.

Comment: This will not do the work, because I use rounded corners image for the root layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this would be to modify the Activity's Theme.  See: [Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Essentially, you should be able to set the background in a custom theme, which would be loaded before any calls to set views.

Edit -

The question has been edited slightly, so the previous answer really only applies to setting the background prior to the call of onCreate.  If instead you want something to show while your app loads, you could create a special Theme for the initial Activity, and set that in the Manifest.

Comment: Could I do it in some method instead? Which one could be appropriate?

Comment: No, if you want it visible before the onCreate runs, then it'll have to be defined in the Manifest via a Theme.  As a bonus though, you can define one Theme and apply it to the entire Application should you desire a consistent appearance.  Or just to a specific Activity if you just need to adjust one.

Comment: See Answer edit.  You can use the Theme to set the background to an image or something - essentially creating a "splash" screen while your app loads.